# Returning XML node with specific attribute name

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, mobile

Hello and thank you in advance,

My question is related to AJAX return/parsing XML information.

I am returning a successful request, but I am return all the XML nodes ngPropertyName. What I would like to accomplish is to return all the ngPropertyName xml nodes just for a specific category (Physical, Medial, Family, ect).

```
    $(xml).find('ngCategory').each(function(){
            $(xml).find('ngPropertyName').each(function(){ 
                var profilePhysicalAt = $(this).text();
                result += "<li>" + profilePhysicalAt + "</li>";
            })
    });

  <ngCategory name="PHYSICAL">
    <ngProperty>
      <ngPropertyID>1287</ngPropertyID>
      <ngPropertyName>Height</ngPropertyName>
      <ListItems>
        <Item id="725">3'0</Item>
        <Item id="726">3'1</Item>
      </ListItems>
    </ngProperty>
<ngProperty>
  <ngPropertyID>1288</ngPropertyID>
  <ngPropertyName>Weight</ngPropertyName>
  <ListItems>
    <Item id="797">25</Item>
    <Item id="798">26</Item>
    <Item id="799">27</Item>
      </ListItems>
    </ngProperty>

   </ngCategory>

  <ngCategory name="Medical">
    <ngProperty>
      <ngPropertyID>1287</ngPropertyID>
      <ngPropertyName>Height</ngPropertyName>
      <ListItems>
        <Item id="725">3'0</Item>
        <Item id="726">3'1</Item>
      </ListItems>
  </ngProperty>
```

Overall, I would like to return all ngPropertyName for that specific category. Currently I am pulling all the ngPropertyName from all my cateogries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use xml DOM.

follow this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_get.asp

Please do not try to extract it using Jquery API.

Comment: Tried this. Didnt work

alert ("Get Physical Nodes");
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else // IE 5/6
 {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xhttp.open("GET","URL",false);
 xhttp.send();
 xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
 
 var a = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ngdataset");
 var b = a.getElementsByTagName("ngCategory")[0];
 var c = b.getElementsByTagName("ngProperty")[0];
 var x = c.getElementsByTagName("ngPropertyID")[0]; 
 var y = x.childNodes[0]; 
 var txt = y.nodeValue;
 
 alert (txt);